# How to make a method take one or two arguments?

Tags: ruby, methods, arguments

I am working on an exercise to make the following tests pass:

```
  describe "repeat" do
    it "should repeat" do
      repeat("hello").should == "hello hello"
    end

    # Wait a second! How can you make the "repeat" method
    # take one *or* two arguments?
    #
    # Hint: *default values*
    it "should repeat a number of times" do
      repeat("hello", 3).should == "hello hello hello"
    end
  end
```

I am not understanding this part for some reason.

When I use this:

```
def repeat(z)
    return z + " " + z
end
```

The first part of the test passes but the second one fails.

Then when I try this:

```
def repeat(z, 2)
    return z * 2
end
```

I get an error the quits the test/rake.

And then when I try:

```
f = 2
def repeat(z, f)
    return z * f
end
```

The test won't pass and I get this message:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
```

I have no idea what is happening here, can someone explain how this works?

Comment: Did you read the part that says "Hint: *default values*"? I googled "ruby default values" and the top several results could all help you answer this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the function like following:

```
def repeat(z, y=2)
    return z * y
end
```

So now, `repeat("hello")` will result: `hellohello` and `repeat("hello", 3)` will return `hellohellohello`

Comment: note `"hello"*2` return `hellohello` not `hello hello`

Comment: @the_prole you are right, edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're doing the Simon Says exercise.

The purpose of this exercise is to teach you how to take one or multiple arguments, using the default values.

Whenever you assign a default value using the "x = default value", it will be used. If the method was called with a different value, it would be used.

In the example below, the default value of number is 2.

```
    def repeat(word, number = 2)
        ([word] * number).join(" ")
    end
```

Using the above, we can call repeat("Hello", 3) and it would result with "hello hello hello"

If we call repeat("Hello"), by default it will return "hello hello"

Hope this helps!!!